# SQL: Insert Into Table 1 From Table 2 then Update Table 2 - Performance Increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, insert-update, not-exists

I am working to increase the speed and performance for a database process that I have inherited.  The basic steps, prior to this process, is a utility uploads about a million or more records into an Upload Table.  That process is pretty quick, but things start to slow down once we start adding/updating/moving items from the Upload Table into other tables in the database.

I have read a few articles stating that using IF NOT EXIST may be quicker than SELECT DISTINCT so I was thinking about refactoring the following code to do so but I was also wondering if there is a way to combine these two queries in order to increase the speed.

The Upload Table contains many columns, I am just showing the Product portion but there is also Store Columns which has the same number of columns as the Product and many other details that are not a one-to-one relationship between tables.

The first query inserts the product into the Product table if it does not already exist, then the next step updates the Upload Table with Product IDs for all the records in the Upload Table.

```
INSERT INTO Product (p.ProductCode, p.ProductDescription, p.ProductCodeQualifier, p.UnitOfMeasure)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ut.ProductCode, ut.ProductDescription, ut.ProductCodeQualifier, ut.UnitOfMeasure
    FROM 
        Upload_Table ut 
    LEFT JOIN
        Product p ON (ut.ProductCode = p.ProductCode) 
                  AND (ut.ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription) 
                  AND (ut.ProductCodeQualifier = p.ProductCodeQualifier)
                  AND (ut.UnitOfMeasure = p.UnitOfMeasure)
    WHERE 
        p.Id IS NULL
        AND ut.UploadId = 123456;
```

```
UPDATE Upload_Table
SET ProductId = Product.Id 
FROM Upload_Table 
INNER JOIN Product ON Upload_Table.ProductCode = Product.ProductCode 
                   AND Upload_Table.ProductDescription = Product.ProductDescription 
                   AND Upload_Table.ProductCodeQualifier = Product.ProductCodeQualifier 
                   AND Upload_Table.UnitOfMeasure = Product.UnitOfMeasure
WHERE (Upload_Table.UploadId = 123456)
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am decent with my understanding of SQL but I am not an expert.

Thanks!

Currently have not tried to make any changes for this part as I am trying to find the best result for speed increases and a better understanding of how this process can be improved.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: *I was thinking about refactoring* - what about actually trying it?

Comment: `insert` and `update` are two separate statements; depending on your RDBMS you may be able to use `merge` and also depending on your RDBMS it might be preferable not to.

Comment: Firstly, for performance questions we need to see query plans (you can share these via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) as well as relevant table and index definitions. Without these, the question is not answerable

Comment: Things that come to mind: `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is often less efficient than `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. Either way, `Product` needs an index over those four columns (any order). And `Upload_Table` needs an index on those four columns also, but with `UploadId` as the first column (you could create this index after bulk inserting). Why does this need `DISTINCT`, why would you have duplicates in the first place? If it is necessary then the above index will help on that also. A `MERGE` may be slightly more efficient, but it comes with its own caveats, and can be complex to write correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations:

1. You can disable triggers, foreign keys, constraints, and indexes before inserting and updating, after these processes you can enable all these again. Because indexes, triggers, and foreign keys accept the inserting (updating) performance very badly.
2. Is not recommended to use `auto-commit` transaction mode during the update or insert process. This is getting a very bad performance, on `auto-commit` mode every time for each after inserting records the transactions automatically will be committed. But, for best performance, I recommended you use `commit` only after inserting 1000 records (or after 10000).
3. If you can, then you can do this process (insert or update) periodically multiple times a day, you can also do this using triggers. I don't know your business logic, maybe this variant will not satisfy you.
4. And don't forget to analyze `executing plan` for your queries.